# Select the remaining text in a line from a log file

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I'm using Bash shell to process some log files, which I need to put in a CSV file. The information I need is **process start date and time**,  **process end date and time** , **Process ID** and **message**

What I did, grep lines including started process and put them in a file, then Grep ended processes and put them in a second file. Once done, I take each file, and use awk to split and extract the information needed, here is a peace of code I'm using,

```
input=starts.txt
while IFS= read -r line
do
    procs=`echo $line | awk  '{ print $6;}' 
    date_s=`echo $line | awk '{ print $1;}'`
    time_s=`echo $line |  awk '{ print $2;}'`
    m1=`echo $line |  awk '{ print $3;}'`
    m2=`echo $line |  awk '{ print $4;}'`
    m3=`echo $line |  awk '{ print $5;}'`
    m4=`echo $line |  awk '{ print $7;}'`
    m5=`echo $line |  awk '{ print $8;}'`
    m6=`echo $line |  awk '{ print $9;}'`

 echo $procs ";" $date_s ";" $time_s ";" $m1 $m2  $m3 $m4 $m5 $m6 

one   < "$input" > result.csv
```

The lines have the following format :

```
02/01/2018 10:32:35      ANR4930I Reclamation process 1320 started for primary      storage pool VM_VTL_POOL automatically, threshold=75,     duration=None. (PROCESS: 1320)
```

I have two issues now :

1. The while loop doesn't end.
2. After extracting the time/date and process ID, I want to put the remaining message in a separate field, without taking word by word and concatenating them (m1 m2 m 3 ...) 
   Also, if there is any improvements that can be done to my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read your task as "move the field 5 (`process number`) to the front, and then output the first 3 fields separated by `;`, followed by `;` and then the remainder.

In Perl I'd do this like so (as a one-liner):

```
perl -a -n -l -e \
    'unshift @F, splice(@F, 5, 1); 
     print join(";", @F[0..2]), ";@F[3..$#F]";' \
    < input.txt > output.csv
```

Result:

`input.txt`:

```
02/01/2018 10:32:35      ANR4930I Reclamation process 1320 started for primary      storage pool VM_VTL_POOL automatically, threshold=75,     duration=None. (PROCESS: 1320) 
02/01/2018 10:32:35      ANR4930I Reclamation process 4567 started for primary      storage pool VM_VTL_POOL automatically, threshold=75,     duration=None. (PROCESS: 1320)
```

`output.csv`:

```
1320;02/01/2018;10:32:35;ANR4930I Reclamation process started for primary storage pool VM_VTL_POOL automatically, threshold=75, duration=None. (PROCESS: 1320)
4567;02/01/2018;10:32:35;ANR4930I Reclamation process started for primary storage pool VM_VTL_POOL automatically, threshold=75, duration=None. (PROCESS: 1320)
```

---

#### Explanation:

`perl -a -n -l -e`

- split each input line at whitespace and put the result into the predefined array `@F`
- process each input line (but don't print it yet)
- use the input separator (`\n`) also as the output separator (quite simplified)
- run the following expression for each input line

`unshift @F, splice(@F, 5, 1);`

- removes the 5<sup>th</sup> element (count=1) from the array `@F` 
  (which contains one line of your input file split at whitespace) and 
  prepends that 5<sup>th</sup> element in front of the array `@F`.

`print join(";", @F[0..2]), ";@F[3..$#F]";'`

- prints the first 2 elements of `@F` with `;` in-between, then
- followed by a literal `;` and then the rest of the array `@F`
   starting at the 3<sup>rd</sup> element up to the end with
   a space as a separator. (`print "@any_array"` prints the items
   separated by a space.)

---

If you want the same code as a script (say `format-messages.pl`), then it looks slighly different because the command line switches to Perl (which are now missing) implicitely add some code which now has to be added explicitely. (Yes, there *are* other ways, but ...)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while(<>) {
    my @F = split;
    unshift @F, splice(@F, 5, 1); 
    print join(";", @F[0..2]), ";@F[3..$#F]\n";
}
```

Do a `chmod +x format-messages.pl` and then run this script with `./format-messages.pl < input.txt > output.csv`

Comment: You are right, that's exactly what I'm trying to do using Bash shell. Thanks

Comment: @AzizAzizos Good to hear I understood it correctly. But it sounds you want a strict _bash_ solution, right? If so, then I'm afraid you will need to wait for another answer... Never mind, though.

Comment: That's right, I tested your script and it's giving the correct results, so just need to convert it to Bash script :) Thanks again.

Comment: @steeldriver I'm not exactly a _bash_ hero but I reckon it is not that difficult to split a line into an array at whitespace, swap two array items, and then print the first few with `;` and the remainder with ` ` as a separator in _bash_. My solution also uses a loop, albeit it's hidden.

Comment: Thank you guys, I never used perl before, is there a simple way to put this code into a script file and run it, something like `perl my_perl_scpt.pl input.txt`  will generate `result.csv`

Comment: @AzizAzizos I just added a script version.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest improvement will be to avoid the shell loop altogether and process each record (line) directly in Awk. For example:

```
$ awk '{
    printf("%s;%s;%s;", $6, $1, $2)
    for(i=3; i<NF;i++) {
      if(i==6) continue; 
      printf("%s ", $i)
    }
    printf("%s\n",$NF)
  }' input
1320;02/01/2018;10:32:35;ANR4930I Reclamation process started for primary storage pool VM_VTL_POOL automatically, threshold=75, duration=None. (PROCESS: 1320)
```

Comment: The last part of the line is still missing  **   duration=None. (PROCESS: 1320) ** not sure if this is because of the comma character

Comment: Well, you didn't provide an example of your desired output - so I based it on the fields from your script. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Sorry :) the desired output is : 

`1320; 02/01/2018 ; 10:32:35;  ANR4930I Reclamation process  started for primary      storage pool VM_VTL_POOL automatically, threshold=75,     duration=None. (PROCESS: 1320)`

Comment: This gives the _very_ same output as the Perl solution. So it cannot be wrong ;-) (kidding, but +1 anyway).

Comment: Bash can read and split fields directly into an array with `read -a [variable]`. The field delimiter(s) is/are taken from `$IFS` as usually.

Comment: Thanks @DavidFoerster don't know why I forgot about that - I've used it may times. Anyhow I've decided to skip the bash implementation altogether.